# ObjectFactory cannot get the target bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I get the way to resolve the question that a bean reference a shorter scope bean. Use ObjectFactory. when i have a test. I got failed `No qualifying bean of type 'com.qunar.scope.SmallScope' available`.

Next is my test code:
**Tester**

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext app = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        BigScope bigScope = app.getBean("bigScope", BigScope.class);
        System.out.println(bigScope.getObjectFactory().getObject());
    }
}
```

**BigScope**

```
@Component
public class BigScope {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<SmallScope> objectFactory;

    public ObjectFactory<SmallScope> getObjectFactory() {
        return objectFactory;
    }

    public void setObjectFactory(ObjectFactory<SmallScope> objectFactory) {
        this.objectFactory = objectFactory;
    }
}
```

**SmallScope**

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class SmallScope {

}
```

**spring.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.qunar.scope"/>
```